# Cannot convert value of type 'Foo!' to expected argument type 'Foo!'

Tags: swift, xctest

I'm baffled by something I've run into a couple of times. I sometimes get errors similar to the following

> Cannot convert value of type 'Foo!' to expected argument type 'Foo!

'

I've searched SO, but haven't really found anything that explains why Foo! isn't the same as Foo!.

Here's an example:

```
// FooViewModel.swift
class FooViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    fileprivate var foo: Foo!
    fileprivate var bar: Bar = Bar()

    init!(model: Foo!) {
        super.init()
        foo = model
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func setFooModel(_ model: Foo!) {
        self.foo = model
    }

    func getFooModel() -> Foo! {
        return self.foo
    }

    func getBar() -> Bar {
        return bar
    }

    func getBlah() -> String {
        return "Blah"
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test that generates the error:

```
import XCTest
@testable import WooHoo

class FooViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testGetBar() {
        var foo = Foo()
        let vm = FooViewModel()

        // The following line generates the error
        vm.setFooModel(foo)

        XCTAssertEqual("Tell us your Foo for the Bar program.", vm.getBlah())
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of variations for `vm.setFooModel(foo)` to no avail, e.g. `vm.setFooModel(foo!)` or declaring foo as `var foo: Foo! = Foo()`.

edit:
Note that the code above is for illustrating the issue I'm running into and is not the operational code.

Comment: Where is the `Foo` type declared? Is it possible that there may be more than one `Foo` declared within different scopes?

Comment: I think you only need to use `Foo!` when you are declaring the variable `foo`  ,on other places just use `Foo`

Comment: What's the point of the `setFooModel` and `getFooModel` methods? Why not just expose the `foo` property? Same for the `getBar` method. Why not simply make the `bar` property with a public read access?

Comment: It's nonsensical to declare a property as implicit unwrapped optional which is initialized in an `init` method. Don't do that. If you want an optional use a regular optional `?` otherwise a non-optional type.

Comment: Why are you using `!` after `init` and the `Foo` argument type? Either the initialiser is failable or it's not. You can't have a return type of a force-unwrapped optional, but you can have a non-optional return type which you force-unwrap in the return statement. Same goes for parameters, if you want a parameter to act non-optional then declare the parameter as non-optional and unwrap at the callsite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out. My view model was part of the tests target. After I set it to the run target only, the issue resolved. FYI.