# How to unit test with 2 classes in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I am writing an app in Swift with Xcode and want to write unit tests to test the classes.
To test the X01Match class, the initializer needs a GameResult object. So I created the following, but get a compile error which I do not know how to resolve. Any suggestions for me?

```
func testGameResult() {

    var gameResult = GameResult.init(gameId: "testMatch", name0: "TestPlayer1", name1: "TestPlayer2")
    var match = X01Match.init(beginScore: 100, nrOfSets: 1, nrOfLegs: 3, nrOfPlayers: 2, gameResult: gameResult)

}
```

[compile error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtb6s.png)

Comment: Unrelated but is there a reason why you're calling .init() rather than instantiating directly GameResult()?

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167309/cannot-convert-value-of-type-foo-to-expected-argument-type-foo) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The Tests checkbox in File Inspector for the X01Match class was unchecked.